# Where can I find the new azure data factory customer feedback page?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse, azure-purview

We used to have Customer/Developer feedback pages where people used to submit product improvement ideas and could see what was the product roadmap in terms of enhancements being built.

However with the revamp of the system - those links are stale now.

Been trying for a while to access the new pages. Could someone please help get the page for ADF, Synapse etc. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (UDPDATE: 10/20/2021) Azure Feedback forum is now live:

https://feedback.azure.com/d365community

[image]

---

Azure services is no longer uses UserVoice to collect feature ideas and suggestions. Our new, improved system will be available later this year. Until the new system is available, use the Azure Services specific forum on [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/index.html) platform.

Example: A feedback provided using MS Q&A platform: [IDEA: Notebook-scoped Python libraries and Search Engine for the libraries (indexing at leat PyPI and Maven Central)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/531506/index.html)

> Azure is working on a new Self-Serve option for customers to share and vote on product feedback. When available, you will be able to go to https://feedback.azure.com/ and share/up-vote product feature ideas.

For more details, refer to [How to send ideas and suggestions to the Synapse team](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-synapse-analytics/how-to-send-ideas-and-suggestions-to-the-synapse-team/ba-p/2665945).